# Dynamic Decremental Connectivity of Cubic Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Let's say I have a fully connected undirected graph (nodes and edges) that is constrained by the fact that all nodes represent coordinates in 3D space and nodes can only be adjacent in the graph if they represent adjacent cubes i.e. (1,0,8) could be adjacent to (0,0,8) or (2,0,8) or (1,0,9).

Now let's say I dynamically start deleting nodes from the graph. I'd like an algorithm that lets me know, at each delete, if the graph connectivity has been broken & if so what the connected components are. Is there a way to optimise the spatial nature of the graph to do so or am I doomed to using standard graph processing algorithms?

I'm thinking I'll need some sort of an algorithm that maintains dynamically the connectivity relationship of nodes in the graph as nodes are deleted from the graph. All I've managed to find so far is A*, jump point search and shortest path algorithms, and I also brushed upon an algorithm here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity#Decremental_connectivity.

Note: my graph can definitely be cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after thinking about this, the best answer I can come up with still does not exploit the spatial constraints of the graph, but I believe it runs with an amortized cost of O(log(n). Here's a sketch of the idea:

First, we compute an arbitrary spanning tree of the graph, starting at any node and choosing arbitrary edges for the tree. Ideally we'd want to make this as balanced as possible i.e. minimize the depth.

Then, at each deletion, we update our spanning tree as follows:

- If the edge deleted is not in the spanning tree, do nothing
- Else, it's a parent-child relationship that's been removed, and we note the child node
- For all children of this child node, we flag them temporarily i.e. we set some marker on each node marking it as part of this affected tree that's possibly broken from the main tree

Now we run this recursive algorithm, starting at the child node. Let's say the algorithm is currently processing node n:

- If there is an edge from n in the graph to an *unmarked* node in the graph, update the spanning tree with this edge and return "true"
- Else for each child of the node, we run the recursive algorithm and proceed as follows
- If the algorithm returned false for any child, then the graph is broken i.e. disconnected
- Else we can choose any node and point our node n at this node and return "true" ourselves

If we actually maintain two separate spanning trees, we can process edge deletions in the background and toggle between using one tree or the other, to improve the efficiency of this for use in a real-time program e.g. a game.